# C++ function does not accept concrete implementation

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-class

I am trying to implement a typesafe event bus. I am stuck with the `EventBus::subscribe` function because it does not accept my concrete event handler. In an earlier version I had my `AbstractEventHandler` implemented as an abstract class only, without it being a template. I had no problem with that implementation. That's why I assume that the actual issue is with the abstract template.

The code below is a stripped down version of my implementation. The first block consist of the "skeleton" of the event bus and its required classes whereas the second block shows an actual implementation of the event, event handler and the main.

The `enum` holds all the different events available. The abstract event is the base of which all concrete events are derived of. The event handler is an abstract template with an event as template class to ensure type-safety. The event bus is responsible for distributing all published events to its respective handlers.

```
enum EVENT_TYPE 
{
    ON_EVENT_1,
    ON_EVENT_2
};

class AbstractEvent 
{
public:
    AbstractEvent() {};
    virtual ~AbstractEvent() {};

    virtual EVENT_TYPE type() = 0;
};

template<class T>
class AbstractEventHandler 
{
public:
    AbstractEventHandler() {};
    virtual ~AbstractEventHandler() {};

    virtual void on_event(T *event) = 0;
};

class EventBus 
{
public:
    EventBus() {};
    virtual ~EventBus() {};

    void subscribe(EVENT_TYPE type, 
                    AbstractEventHandler<AbstractEvent> *eventHandler) {
        // Add handler to vector for further use
    }

    void publish(AbstractEvent *event) {
        // send event to each handler in respective vector
    }
};
```

Below are my concrete event and event handler and the main()

```
class ConcreteEvent : public AbstractEvent 
{
public:
    ConcreteEvent() {};
    virtual ~ConcreteEvent() {};

    EVENT_TYPE type() {
        return ON_EVENT_1;
    };
};

class ConcreteEventHandler : public AbstractEventHandler<ConcreteEvent> 
{
public:
    ConcreteEventHandler() {}
    virtual ~ConcreteEventHandler() {};

    void on_event(ConcreteEvent *event) {
        // Do something
    };
};

int main() 
{
    EventBus *eventBus = new EventBus();

    ConcreteEventHandler handler = ConcreteEventHandler();

    // This failes!
    eventBus->subscribe(ON_EVENT_1, &handler);
}
```

The compiler returns with an error saying that there is no matching function for call to

```
EventBus::subscribe(EVENT_TYPE, ConcreteEventHandler*)
```

and that the only candidates are

```
void EventBus::subscribe(EVENT_TYPE, AbstractEventHandler<AbstractEvent>*)
```

How can I implement my EventBus::subscribe method to accept concrete implementations of my abstract class?

**Update: Solution**

I have changed the method description of `EventBus::subscribe` to the following and it now works nicely:

```
template<typename T>
void subscribe(EVENT_TYPE type, AbstractEventHandler<T> *eventHandler) {

}
```

Thanks, Rohan, for your hints! They helped me to find this solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because, `ConcreteEventHandler` is a subclass of `AbstractEventHandler<ConcreteEvent>` and not `AbstractEventHandler<AbstractEvent>`.

This might seem surprising, but `AbstractEventHandler<ConcreteEvent>` cannot be a subclass of `AbstractEventHandler<AbstractEvent>` even though `ConcreteEvent` is a subclass of `AbstractEvent`.

The reason is because, with templates, templating as you wish does not guarantee type safety. Let us look at an example. Let's go over the standard paradigm of a base-class `Animal` and sub-classes `Cat` and `Dog`. Let's say we have a list of Animals:

```
std::list<Animals>* animals;
```

and a list of cats:

```
std::list<Cat> cats;
```

The following, is NOT a valid cast:

```
animals = &cats;
```

The reason is, because, if I am to do this,

```
animals->add(new Dog("Ben"));
```

I would actually add a `Dog` to a list of `Cat`s. `cats.last()` here would actually return a `Dog`. So, in this case, you are essentially adding a `Dog` to a list of `Cat`s. I've seen enough Looney Tunes episodes to know that this is not a good idea:

```
cats.last().meow();
```

The above is definitely not true, as we all know that a `Dog` can only `bowbow()`.

**EDIT**

To answer your question, here is what I suggest you do; Let `ConcreteEventHandler` inherit from `AbstractEventHandler<AbstractEvent>`, and within the code, wherever you use a `ConcreteEvent`, use a `dynamic_case` to cast the `AbstractEvent` to a `ConcreteEvent`. This will use run-time introspection, which might impact performance a little (also I have seen quite a few people opposed to using a dynamic cast), but you will be able to successfully perform a valid upcast of the datatype.

Comment: Okay, true, but it doesn't answer the question - How can I implement my EventBus::subscribe method to accept concrete implementations of my abstract class?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I understand the issue better now. The problem is that I need AbstractEventHandler<AbstractEvent> in oder to force the concrete handlers to implement the correct on_event() method.

Comment: Are you both like the same person?

Answer (score 1):

Rohan already answered why the code doesn't compile, however I would like to suggest another approach.

You could implement it in a way that **the Eventhandler subscribes directly to the EventGenerator**. This way there is a direct link between generating and handling the event.
The event should then hold a reference to its generator to let it access the subscribed handlers and the eventbus calls a method on the event to let it handle itself.

This way, the eventbus is unaware of eventhandlers and you don't even need an eventtype enum.
However, you need different eventgenerators that need to be accessible by different eventhandlers as opposed to one eventbus.  Every eventhandler can handle only one event, so if more events are needed, eventhandlers should be aggregated (by delegation or inheritence).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I don't want to go along this route for two reasons:

1/ The event bus is part of an API and I don't want to expose the classes that generate the events. 

2/ As the project grows I fear of ending up in an uncontrollable web of interconnections between handlers and event generators.

Comment: Fair enough, it is your project.  About 2/, the risk is minimized with a layered approach, where the higher modules know the lower modules and can subscribe and where events are only sent from lower to higher modules.

Answer (score -2):

Your `AbstractEventHandler<T>` class should inherit `AbstractEvent`. This was probably your intent, you just forgot to write it.

```
template<class T>
class AbstractEventHandler
    :public AbstractEvent
{
public:
    AbstractEventHandler() {};
    virtual ~AbstractEventHandler() {};

    virtual void on_event(T *event) = 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 not just for being wrong, but for not even trying to compile the code.

Comment: semantically, an eventhandler should never inherit an event.  It is not an event, it is what is handling that event.